# HTMLForm database best practices: RDBM, normalization, required/optional fields, adding/removing fields

Tags: sql, forms, normalization

I work for a college that has multiple types of forms.
We are converting our old system (form data -> email) to a more efficient system (sql) for many reasons: reporting, speed, mailbox limitations, etc.

I understand normalization and sql commands just fine... I'm hung up on these:

1. required vs optional fields (null or separate table)
2. changes to the form (adding/removing fields and how it's reflected in the table design)
3. 1:1 form to table ratio or 1:N form to table ratio
4. If 1:N, will this affect the reports of each form?

Do you know of a site/book/article/tutorial that gives great information on how to store form data in a database that touches my concerns?

or, could you describe what is a "tried and true" method?

I'd like to aim for 3rd or 4th normalization if possible.

---

My initial thoughts are:

1. create a table, "application," that has fields for all required (permanent) data.
2. create a table, "application_extra," that has the fields: application_id, field_title and field_value

but would this be okay for reporting?

thanks!

Comment: Are you storing form data? Or actual forms (structure, elements, etc)? These are 2 entirely different things.

Comment: just the data upon submission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're dealing with static forms, there's no real risk that the form/table will change, and even if it will, it will require a quick change to the table columns, and a bit to PHP submission code (i.e. the query), and that's it.

Dynamic forms a bit different (Dynamic forms being forms generated by the server somehow, either by user input, or by server conditions). You'll need 2 tables per form, one for the strucutre of the form, and one for the data saved in it, where the results are saved in a many-to-one relationship.

Example for structure talbe:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `form_structure` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'Name of the form element as appeared on its name attribute',
  `type` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'text' COMMENT 'Type of the form element (text, password, checkbox etc).',
  `label` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'Label for the form element.',
  `can_be_null` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Whether the form element can be null.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```